# How to: relationships between Spree::Product and your other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

in my Rails 3.2 app with Spree I'd like to have a `WishList` model that has a `has_many` relationship regarding to the `Spree::Product` model provided by Spree. I have already created a decorator class to declare a `belongs_to` relationship into `Spree::Product` but how can I refer to `Spree::Product` inside another model I've created myself.

I tried both

```
class WishList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

and

```
class WishList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spree_products
end
```

and none of them worked. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:class_name` option:

```
class WishList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spree_products, :class_name => 'Spree::Product'
end
```